# Why ViewModel's object shouldn't manipulate database directly?

Tags: android, design-patterns, dao, android-architecture-components

I am learning *Android Architecture Components*.

For exemple, and be more easier to understand, If i want to build a TO DO LIST app, my item creation DAO should be

```
@Dao
public interface ItemDao {
    @Insert
    long insertItem(Item item);
}
```

and my viewModel could be use this DAO to insert an item in my TODO list. 
But, in *architecture component*, it is recommanded to NOT manipulate the database by the viewmodel but by the repository.

So, the code should be like that

```
public class ItemDataRepository {

    private final ItemDao itemDao;

    public ItemDataRepository(ItemDao itemDao) { this.itemDao = itemDao; }

    // --- CREATE ---

    public void createItem(Item item){ itemDao.insertItem(item); }
```

It seems redundant when we cannot understand why.

My question is : why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the `Repository` for a couple of reasons:

- **Separation of concern** I let the repo be responsible for downloading and storing all the data. That way the `ViewModel` doesn't have to know any specifics about where the data is coming from, e.g. if it's from an API or a cache. It also makes it easier to write Unit tests for the `ViewModel`, since all the database and API logic should already be tested in Unit tests for the `Repository`.
- **Reusability** Lets say you fetch the data from an API and store in a database. If you put the code in the `ViewModel` and then want to perform the same actions from another place in the app, you need to copy paste the code. By having it in a `Repository` you can easily share the implementation.
- **Share data** If you have multiple screens that show parts of the same data set, having one `Repository` passed around between the screens make it easy to share the data. No more trying to pass large amount of data in `Bundle` and `Intent`.
- **Lifecycle** Let's say you download data from an API to show in your view. If you fetch the data in the `ViewModel` you will have to re-download it when the screen is closed and re-opened, since the `ViewModel` is discarded. However if you store it in the `Repository` it can use the `Application` lifecycle, so when you revisit the screen again, the data is already in the cache.